# Unreal Engine V4.18 Why does this cause a crash and how could i fix it?

Tags: c++, casting, game-engine, unreal-engine4

This is code that I'm using for a ammo pickup, the problem is when i walk over the sphere component unreal crashes. I have narrowed the problem down to these two lines (commented) but i don't know how i would fix this. Another problem of mine is what do i put in my second cast statement to make this work?

```
void AAmmoPack::NotifyActorBeginOverlap(AActor* OtherActor)
{
    Super::NotifyActorBeginOverlap(OtherActor);
    ASCharacter* MyCharacter = Cast<ASCharacter>(OtherActor);
    if (MyCharacter) {
        //ASWeapon* Weapon = Cast<ASWeapon>();
        //Destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're trying to cast void to ASWeapon.
In your code `ASWeapon* Weapon = Cast<ASWeapon>( /*HERE SHOULD BE OBJECT YOU CAST TO WEAPON*/  );`